# How to get a page source of changed website with selenium?

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get the source code of the page after changing it, I send a request to the page, then the page opens in my browser, I select some data with my hands, and after that, a table appears with the necessary data, how after all these operations can I take this table or get full page code after changes

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

links=['https://priem.gubkin.ru/#/page/enrollment']
s=Service(executable_path='D:\\university\\geckodriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)
try:
    driver.maximize_window()

    for i in range(0,len(links)):
        driver.get(links[i])
        # time.sleep(25)

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody")))

        with open('GUBKINA.html', 'w') as file:
            file.write(element)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

I tried to get this table with the help of waits and finding a class of  this table, but a program can't find this element and write that nosuchelenterror and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the links that you want are in an iFrame. Try something like this:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe") #find the iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe) # go into it

items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span") # do stuff
for item in items:
    print(unidecode(item.text))

driver.switch_to.default_content() # exit the iframe
```

I couldn't find any elements with the class of "tbody", but the CSS for that is on the site. The code above prints the following in unicode:

```
Spisok abiturientov
Forma obucheniia
Forma obucheniia
Forma obucheniia
```

Comment: i have changed to  "element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/app-root/div/home/mat-card/div[2]'))); ",but it doesn t work too, i had seen that the table not in iframe,it was a mistake to write css_selector,i write it because tested this code and forgot to return to normal finding of element

Comment: This path does not exist: html/body/app-root/div/home/mat-card/div[2] at least on my side.

Comment: This path does exist but its inside the iframe: html/body/app-root/div/home

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another approach: Use their Ajax API (the URL from they get the data for the table in Json form):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://transfer.priem.gubkin.ru/abiturients_list/api/api.php'

params = {
    "act": "search",
    "method": "get",
    "educationTypeId": "6",
    "contestGroupId": "263",
}

data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"]).explode("ballsBySubjects")
df = pd.concat(
    [df, df.pop("ballsBySubjects").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("bbs_")], axis=1
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   position           snils   fio  originalExistence originalType individualAchievementsBalls totalBalls  needHostel  priority entranceBalls benefit  isLastPerson orders_before       bbs_name  bbs_id bbs_ball  bbs_priority
0         1  173-112-079 27  None              False                                     None       None        True         2          None                 False                Специальность      17     None             1
1         2  134-581-746 69  None              False                                     None       None        True         1          None                 False                Специальность      17     None             1
2         3  174-629-198 02  None              False                                     None       None       False         2          None                 False                Специальность      17     None             1
```

---

The parameters you find in Web Developer Tools when you switch to Network Tab and fill the form (the screenshot):

[image]